# Does .net have different operation modes?

Tags: .net, performance

I just read in an article about JIT Compilation that Java has two modes of operation (client vs. server) which employ different amounts of JIT complation / runtime optimization.

Does .net provide similar modes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various runtime modes in .NET, but they are mostly related to the garbage collector used.  This has a major impact on the runtime, and is especially useful when configuring server programs (and/or highly threading programs where user interaction is lighter).

For details, see the [`<gcServer>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx) and [`<gcConcurrent>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhwwzef8.aspx) configuration options.

There are various other configuration options that impact the runtime of the CLR, as well, such as whether to [commit the full thread stack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882564.aspx), where to [look for assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyshaw37.aspx), etc - but these are more just "options" rather than major changes in runtime behavior.

However, this does not change the JIT configuration and optimization, which is more platform specific (x86 vs x64, etc) rather than configuration specific.